# How to get a click event on Horizontalscrollview in android?

Tags: android, onclick, horizontalscrollview, horizontallist, clicklistener

I have a requirement to design a Horizontalscroll list to show the list of dynamically obtained images in the list.Upon clicking on any item on the list it has to be shown on the Image view above the list.I tried many examples provided in the blogs. But they dont extend thier explanations towards obtaining the index of the Horizontalscrollview or getting resourceid of the image on which user has tapped. Knowledged please guide me on this.

Ps. I tried with galleryview as well But, I am not supposed to work using this as it is deprecated.

Regards,
Gururaj

Answer (score 0):

Elsalam Alykom
you can use [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) 
try this link
http://android-er.blogspot.com.eg/2014/04/example-of-viewpager-with-custom.html

Comment: Thanks Moustafa for the link.. But i have another issue.. Here using this will load a single image at any one moment of time. But i wanted list of imagesto be shown together at any time. like i need to show 2-3 images at a time on the Horizontalscroll list.Any help?